# Install gcc and build-essential offline rhel

Tags: linux, gcc, rhel

I am trying to install GCC in a rhel 7 server

But I'm getting this error.

```
# sudo rpm -ivh gcc-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        cpp = 4.8.5-39.el7 is needed by gcc-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64
        glibc-devel >= 2.2.90-12 is needed by gcc-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64
        libmpc.so.3()(64bit) is needed by gcc-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64
        libmpfr.so.4()(64bit) is needed by gcc-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64
```

How to solve this error. Is there a guide to install gcc and do ubuntu's build-essential equivalent in rhel  7 offline

Any suggestion would help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can get a free subscription from Red Hat using https://developers.redhat.com/.

This allows to register your RHEL machine with Red Hat yum repositories and to use yum directly with Red Hat.

Comment: But that is an offline server . and I have to SCP RPMs and install there

Comment: You can try to download CentOS 7 RPM from http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/. In general CentOS7 binaries are compatible with RHEL 7.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the Red Hat productized version called Developer Toolset (DTS). Instructions are [here](https://developers.redhat.com/products/developertoolset/hello-world). This installs the additional version alongside the original (because if you replace the original it can break the OS). Enable the channels per step 1, then check which versions are available to you. DTS is part of your subscription including the developer sub that is mentioned above.

[added] FYI [GCC 9](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/05/29/red-hat-software-collections-3-5-brings-updates-for-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7/) is now available